# Regex expression - one or multiple strings seperated by comma

Tags: regex

Novice regex question here.

I need a regex that will accept one or more of the following strings. If there is multiple strings, they need to be separated by a comma.

```
foo
bar
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to go through a regex tutorial if you intend to start using regex in your scripts

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(foo|bar)(,(foo|bar))*$
```

does that. The [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) are not necessary, you could also write this (slightly more efficient) with non-capturing groups as

```
^(?:foo|bar)(?:,(?:foo|bar))*$
```

To avoid repeats, you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(foo|bar)(?:,(?!\1)(?:foo|bar))?$
```

(Notice the `?` instead of `*` - if only a single repetition is possible, this makes more sense.)

This approach quickly becomes complicated when a higher number of strings is to be checked. While it's theoretically possible to do that with a regex as well, it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the same entry being repeated? This regex allows foo,foo and would like it to prevent a string being repeated

Comment: @user2440741 - something like `/^(foo|bar)(,(?!\1).+)*$/` should do the trick

Comment: @user2440741 That doesn't accept `foo,foo`, but it will accept `foo,bar,foo`.

Comment: @user2440741 It works for me - but I only tested it in JavaScript - as you didn't specify a language I just had a quick crack at it in JS.

Comment: @Jerry: No, it doesn't. Did you notice the `?` instead of `*`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker the OP was referring to SmokeyPHP's regex, which is what I was referring back to. Yours will not match `foo,foo` nor `foo,bar,foo`.